# QGIS 3.4.5 enable trace tool

Tags: qgis-3, snapping

I'm using QGIS 3.4.5 and created a line shape layer.
I have another line layer in my project that I want to create and trace the geometry of the other layer.
I activated the "add line object" button and also checked out the "node tool".
Snapping is enabled in settings --> options.
Using another CRS for the layers doesn't help either.
Can somebody tell me how I can activate the "trace tool" in "snapping toolbar"?
Proceeding like this, the "trace tool" isn't active.
Kind regards, Larissa

Comment: I presume you have activated the snap tool (s)? You have to do that first in order to be able to activate the tracing tool.

Comment: thanks a lot, I see it's very easy to active the tracing. Cheers, Larissa